# Georgian prefix-suffix lists!

Tags: georgian

I'm wondering if there are some lists for Georgian prefix-suffix changing parts of speech (with some explanations about the changes occur in roots or stems (e.g syncope ch'am -> ch'm))  sorted in such categories, either verb/non-verb-based or noun/adjective roots. For Verb-based one can find Verb -> Noun ones like :stsavl (teach) > mastsavlebeli (teacher) ; Adj -> Noun like: lamazi > silamaze ; Noun -> Noun: t'vali (eye)> sat'vale (glasses) or mzareuli(cook) > samzareulo (kitchen).

Comment: Did you find anything? A 'good grammar' should cover these, whoever, I also haven't found a concise summery. I suspect the Russian based "живой язык" publications - might have this table, they have very good tables in their Finnish Grammar, I haven't looked at it yet (available on Ozon store for example)
(OT) I know a suitable book for Finnish  "A Grammar Book of Finnish Paperback – 2011
by Leila White "